# get user email from Firebase with query

Tags: firebase

I want to implement search by email in my app but kinda stuck with the design of query.
my data structure looks like this

```
users {
      uid {
          email: email@email.com
```

i tried the following query:

```
console.log(reqestEmail); // proper email here
new Firebase(USERS)
  .startAt(reqestEmail)
  .endAt(reqestEmail)
  .once('value', function(snap){
     var foundUser = snap.val();

     console.log(foundUser) // output is null
    });
```

I guess the problem is in the fact i have a uid in the path. But how to to implement search with this data structure — if i this uid is the needed result?

If it is important using Firebase 2.0.2 and AngularFire 0.9

Sorry guys: noob here. Also in danger of suspention of account.

Comment: You first need to call `orderByChild` and then `startAt` and `endAt`. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/orderbychild.html

Comment: But what argument should i pass when my uid is unknown(it is the one i search for)? Am i doing it right with this data structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to first order by email address, so that you can then filter on it:

```
console.log(reqestEmail); // proper email here
new Firebase(USERS)
  .orderByChild('email')
  .startAt(reqestEmail)
  .endAt(reqestEmail)
  .once('value', function(snap){
     var foundUser = snap.val();
     console.log(foundUser) // output is correct now
  });
```

Working sample in this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/fenavu/2/edit?js,console

Comment: Thank you so much, this is correct. Not obvious at all from the docs, if you ask me.

Comment: It would be more constructive if you said which documentation you did read and how that page could be improved so that it would have been obvious how to accomplish this.

Comment: Im sorry. If anyone from Firebase read this, IMO this blog post on your site is confusing.
https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html
Especially the part «Find a user by email address (WHERE email = x)». The thing that i need to call orderByChild is not stated. It whould be nice to mention situation similar to mine with unknown key.

Comment: That blog post pre-dates the `orderByChild` functionality by a year. I would normally not consider blog posts part of product documentation, precisely for that reason: they won't be updated when the product changes. That said: the approach in that post would still work and is still useful in cases where Firebase's automatic index generation is too limited (such as when you want to search on a multi-value field, say "email address**es**). And it would of course be nice of "someone" would add a note to the post about `orderByChild`.